# How to get the Rails Guides for the desired version of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I assume that edge guides have `edgeguides` in the domain name (for example http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), and that guides for older versions of Rails have the version in the path (for example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/getting_started.html).

But when googling I came across http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html, which I assumed would be for the latest released version of Rails. But it redirected me to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html (the migrations page for the current version of Rails is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

How does Rails Guides work with versions of Rails, and how do I correctly get the Rails Guides for the version of Rails I'm using?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Rails Github](https://github.com/rails/rails).

Or go to the [Rails Guide website](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). There you'll find the current Rails Guide as well as links to past versions of the Rails Guides including:

- [Version 5.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/)
- [Version 4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/)
- [Version 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/)
- [Version 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/)
- [Version 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/)
- [Version 2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the version between the root url and the topic:

```
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/<version>/<topic>
```

---

For example:

Latest: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Rails 6.1: [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/**v6.1**/initialization.html](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/initialization.html)

Rails 3.1: [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/**v3.1**/initialization.html](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/initialization.html)

---

All the available versions are listed at the very top of [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) page.